# CSS counter only resetting on the first few elements

Tags: html, css

Today, I come to you with the question of how to get the counters reset on this page-fragment.

I want to have a numbered `"content"` section:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: CountHead2 CountHead3 CountHead4 CountHead5;
}

.headCounter:before {
  counter-increment: CountHead2;
  counter-reset: CountHead3;
  counter-reset: CountHead4;
  counter-reset: CountHead5;
  content: counter(CountHead2) '. ';
}

.head3:before {
  counter-increment: CountHead3;
  content: counter(CountHead2) '.' counter(CountHead3) ' ';
}
.head4:before {
  counter-increment: CountHead4;
  content: counter(CountHead2) '.' counter(CountHead3) '.'
    counter(CountHead4) '';
}
.head5:before {
  counter-increment: CountHead5;
  counter-increment: CountHead3 1;
  counter-increment: CountHead4 1;
  content: counter(CountHead2) '.' counter(CountHead3) '.'
    counter(CountHead4) '.' counter(CountHead5) ' ';
}
```

```html
<h1>Test Counter</h1>
<h2 class="headCounter">1</h2>
<h3 class="head3">Test 1</h3>
<h4 class="head4">Test 4</h4>
<h5 class="head5">Test 5</h5>
<h2 class="headCounter">2</h2>
<h3 class="head3">Test2</h3>
<h4 class="head4">test 4</h4>
<h2 class="headCounter">3</h2>
<h3 class="head3">Test3</h3>
<h4 class="head4">Test 4</h4>
<h5 class="head5">Test 5</h5>
<h5 class="head5">Test 5</h5>
<h5 class="head5">Test 5</h5>
<h3 class="head3">Test3</h3>
<h3 class="head3">Test3</h3>
<h2 class="headCounter">4</h2>
```

For the first set of h2 - h5 everything is displayed the right way, for the subsequent elements, I fear, I am missing some form of counter-reset.

[image]

Can anyone nudge me in the correct direction here?
All the best,
K

Answer (score 0):

I have commented and modify your code below.

About the counters in CSS :

- `counter-increment` incrment by one the following counter, like : `counter-increment: myCounterToBeIncrement;`
- `counter-set` set the followings counters to given values, like : `counter-set: myCounterToSetToZero 0 myCounterToSetToTen 10;`
- `counter-reset` set a counter to zero, like : `counter-reset: myCounterToSetToZero;`, equivalent to : `counter-set: myCounterToSetToZero 0;`

In your case, at each lvl of headers with counters you need to :

- increment the linked counter
- reset all the smaller counters
- defined the preceding text of your title

```css
/* Counters initialization */
body {
  counter-reset: CountHead2 CountHead3 CountHead4 CountHead5;
}

/* On your example h1 has no counters attached, so we start with h2 */
h2:before{
  /* We increment the linked counter */
  counter-increment: CountHead2;
  /* We set the smaller counters to 0 */
  counter-set: CountHead3 0 CountHead4 0 CountHead5 0;
  /* We defined the automatic text from the counter */
  content:
    counter(CountHead2) '. ';
}

/* We will do the same for all the smaller titles */
h3:before{
  counter-increment: CountHead3;
  counter-set: CountHead4 0 CountHead5 0;
  content:
    counter(CountHead2) '.'
    counter(CountHead3) '. ';
}

h4:before{
  counter-increment: CountHead4;
  counter-set: CountHead5 0;
  content:
    counter(CountHead2) '.'
    counter(CountHead3) '.'
    counter(CountHead4) '. ';
}

h5:before{
  counter-increment: CountHead5;
  content:
    counter(CountHead2) '.'
    counter(CountHead3) '.'
    counter(CountHead4) '.'
    counter(CountHead5) '. ';
}
```

```html
<h1>Header lvl 1 (no counters)</h1>

<h2>Header lvl 2 (counters linked to h2 will never reset)</h2>
<h3>Header lvl 3</h3>
<h3>Header lvl 3 (we do see counter of h3 increased)</h3>
<h4>Header lvl 4</h4>
<h5>Header lvl 5</h5>

<h2>Header lvl 2</h2>
<h3>Header lvl 3 (we do see counter of h3 have been reset by h2)</h3>
<h4>Header lvl 4</h4>

<h2>Header lvl 2</h2>
<h3>Header lvl 3</h3>
<h4>Header lvl 4</h4>
<h5>Header lvl 5</h5>
<h5>Header lvl 5</h5>
<h5>Header lvl 5</h5>

<h3>Header lvl 3</h3>
<h3>Header lvl 3</h3>

<h2>Header lvl 2</h2>
```

Comment: It's still not resetting the counter in 3.x , the x should restart at 1 :-)

Comment: You problem is not clear, I have now assumed that you would need a reset for all smaller titles at each title level. Is that what you need ?

Answer (score 0):

Upon being lss inclined that this won't ever work, I figured it out:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            body {
                counter-reset: CountHead2 CountHead3 CountHead4 CountHead5;
            }

            .headCounter:before {
                counter-increment: CountHead2;
                content: counter(CountHead2) '. ';
            }

            .headCounter {
                counter-reset: CountHead3 CountHead4 CountHead5;
            }

            .head3:before {
                counter-increment: CountHead3;
                content: counter(CountHead2) '.' counter(CountHead3) ' ';
            }
            .head3 {
                counter-reset: CountHead4 CountHead5;
            }

            .head4:before {
                counter-increment: CountHead4;
                content: counter(CountHead2) '.' counter(CountHead3) '.'
                    counter(CountHead4) ' ';
            }
            .head4 {
                counter-reset: CountHead5;
            }

            .head5:before {
                counter-increment: CountHead5;
                content: counter(CountHead2) '.' counter(CountHead3) '.'
                    counter(CountHead4) '.' counter(CountHead5) ' ';
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test Counter</h1>
        <h2 class="headCounter">1</h2>
        <h3 class="head3">Test 1</h3>
        <h4 class="head4">Test 4</h4>
        <h4 class="head4">1.1.2</h4>
        <h4 class="head4">1.1.3</h4>
        <h5 class="head5">Test 5</h5>
        <h3 class="head3">Test 1</h3>
        <h3 class="head3">1.3</h3>
        <h4 class="head4">1.3.1</h4>
        <h2 class="headCounter">2</h2>
        <h3 class="head3">Test2</h3>
        <h4 class="head4">test 4</h4>
        <h2 class="headCounter">3</h2>
        <h3 class="head3">Test3</h3>
        <h4 class="head4">Test 4</h4>
        <h5 class="head5">whop</h5>
        <h5 class="head5">whap</h5>
        <h3 class="head3">Test3</h3>
        <h3 class="head3">Test3</h3>
        <h3 class="head3">Test3</h3>
        <h4 class="head4">Test-whoops</h4>
        <h5 class="head5">Test 5 asdasd</h5>
        <h5 class="head5">Test 5</h5>
        <h5 class="head5">Test 5</h5>
        <h3 class="head3">Test3</h3>
        <h3 class="head3">Test3</h3>
        <h2 class="headCounter">4</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```